Is there an equivalent of Newton's laws for fields?
When discussing classical fields (I mean simple stuff like ordinary strings or water waves), could one construct some kind of Newton's law of motions for fields?

The first law is unusual in this context because we take the Eulerian view that the fields are there and the values move. But from the second law it can be generalized to fields propagate or do not move in the absence of forces (in inertial reference frames). Something can be said about Galilean transformations.

The second law is the cleanest to generalize from Lagrangian mechanics,
$$\dot{\pi}=\rho\ddot\phi=\nabla\cdot(T\nabla \phi)+f$$
where $\phi$ is the field, $\pi$ is the momentum of the field, $T$ is some tension term and $f$ are the sum of external forces.

The third law is hard to generalize. I do not see what the cause and effect  implies  here. There are two components of where the momentum goes, into the field and into the interacting field.


Has this been attempted yet?

Aren't the Navier-Stokes conservation of momentum?

@User198 but conservation of momentum is not exactly the third law, even if the two are equivalent.

Stuff like ordinary strings or water does obey Newton's three laws, what is there to construct? The Navier-Stokes or the Euler equations for water are derived from 2nd law by using appropriate mathematical description and assumptions about viscosity and compressibility. Waves on a string are described by a wave equation on a string, which is also derived from 2nd law and some assumption about elastic behaviour of the string.

@JánLalinský I am looking for the equivalence of the third law of motion in the language of fields. If I have a two particles that interact through a field, I would like to say something about how the field conserves momentum because of the third law. Forces created by the particle impart reaction force by the field, but how do I write that mathematically?

When two particles interact through a field, their interaction is no longer instantaneous, and 3rd law no longer holds (e.g. magnetic forces between two particles). Total momentum (including matter momentum and EM field momentum) is still locally conserved, but this isn't described in terms of 3rd law and forces, but in terms of local conservation equation and stress tensor (four-divergence of net stress-energy tensor equals zero).

Already in classical physics, conservation of momentum is a different thing from 3rd law. 3rd law implies conservation of momentum, but conservation of momentum is not expressed in terms of forces obeying 3rd law, it is expressed in terms of momenta and possibly their derivatives, e.g. as $\sum_n \mathbf p_n = const.$ or $\frac{d}{dt}\sum_n \mathbf p_n = 0$.
